# jQuery: progress bar progressing with each click

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, progress

so I am trying to create a progress bar that will show a users current step number and a progress bar that will fill or unfill based on whether the user clicks "next" or "back".

here is my jQuery:

```
    var totalSteps = 30;
    var barWidth = $('.barWrap').width();
    var prog = barWidth/totalSteps;
    var currentValue = parseInt($("#stepNum").text(),10);
    var nextValue = currentValue + 1;
    var prevValue = currentValue - 1;

    // console.log(perc);

    $('#bar').css('width', prog);

    $('#nextNav').click(function(){
        $('#bar').css('width', prog + prog);
        $("#stepNum").text(nextValue);
    });

    $('#backNav').click(function(){
        $('#bar').css('width', prog - prog);
        $("#stepNum").text(prevValue);
    });
```

It works somewhat when you click next the progress bar fills with the correct amount of fill color based on the total steps specified (totalSteps = 30) and the step number changes.

But when I click "next" again nothing changes and when I click back the step number changes to 0 and the progress bar is empty.

So I need it to add the chunk and change the number up when "next" is clicked and remove the chunk and change the number down when "back" is clicked.

Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agon024/4xdbopgn/3/)** with all the code.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't updating any of your variables. Try this (I also added some logic to make sure it doesn't go out of bounds):

https://jsfiddle.net/4xdbopgn/5/

```
var totalSteps = 30;
var barWidth = $('.barWrap').width();
var prog = barWidth/totalSteps;
var currentValue = 1;
var maxValue = 30;

$('#bar').css('width', prog);

$('#nextNav').click(function(){
    currentValue++;
    if (currentValue > maxValue)
        currentValue = maxValue;

    $('#bar').css('width', prog * currentValue);
    $("#stepNum").text(currentValue);
});

$('#backNav').click(function(){
    currentValue--;
    if (currentValue < 1)
        currentValue = 1;

    $('#bar').css('width', prog * currentValue);
    $("#stepNum").text(currentValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`prog + prog` will return same value always. Try like following.

```
var totalSteps = 30;
var barWidth = $('.barWrap').width();
var prog = barWidth / totalSteps;
var currentValue = parseInt($("#stepNum").text(), 10);

$('#bar').css('width', prog);

$('#nextNav').click(function () {
    currentValue++;
    currentValue = currentValue > totalSteps ? totalSteps : currentValue;

    $('#bar').css('width', prog * currentValue);
    $("#stepNum").text(currentValue);
});

$('#backNav').click(function () {
    currentValue--;
    currentValue = currentValue < 0 ? 0 : currentValue;

    $('#bar').css('width', prog * currentValue);
    $("#stepNum").text(currentValue);
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4xdbopgn/7/)**

Comment: That is actually doubling the fill bar every click. Paste your code into my fiddle so you can see what it is doing. and when you hit back everything still goes to 0. Plus I need the step to increase by one and decrease by one based on whether "next" or "back" is clicked.